# 'ILifetimeScope' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net, visual-studio, autofac

I am using Visual Studios 2015

While excuting a project i am getting the following error:

> CS0012    The type 'ILifetimeScope' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'.

Can some one tell me what to add in this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have a missing reference to Autofac - the Dependency Injection framework, from within an Asp.Net project.

Installing the nuget package `autofac` will cover this error - but you may well end up running into other errors if your project needs autofac integration packages for whatever flavour of Asp.Net you are using. I suggest checking out the [autofac integration documentation](http://fac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/index.html).

Comment: I am also getting meesage that nuget manager is not loading properly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197675/nuget-package-didnot-load-correctly-vs-2015

Can you please tell mee what to do? Thanks