# Nuget package didnot load correctly (VS 2015)

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, nuget-package

If i open my visual Studios, I am getting a message which says "Unable to load nuget package" refer to activity.xml

here is the log from xml:

> CreateInstance failed for package [NuGetPackage]Source:
>   'mscorlib' Description: Could not load file or assembly
>   'NuGet.Tools, Version=3.4.4.1321, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file
>   specified.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'NuGet.Tools, Version=3.4.4.1321,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.
> File name: 'NuGet.Tools,
>   Version=3.4.4.1321, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)
>    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String
>   typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder,
>   Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes,
>   Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>  
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String
>   typeName)
>    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String
>   assemblyName, String typeName)
> 
> WRN:
>   Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
> To enable
>   assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to
>   1.
> Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
> To turn this
>   feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
>       {5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}

Please tell me how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same error after moving to VS 2015. I found a link that recommended:

> 1. Uninstall NuGet Package Manager Tools => Extensions and Updates =>Installled => Tools
> 2. Click Uninstall on the Nuget Package Manager option to remove NuGet.
> 3. Restart Visual Studio
> 4. Reinstall NuGet Package Manager by Extensions and Updates

https://forums.asp.net/t/2102490.aspx?Nuget+package+didnot+load+correctly+VS+2015+

This worked for me and I no longer get an error.